# Generics casting issue when implementing efficient pubsub in C# that invokes listeners when subtype messages are submitted

Tags: java, c#, publish-subscribe

I am trying to implement an efficient pubsub module in C#. The requirement is simple: not much performance requirement when subscribing/unsubscribing, but must be as performant as possible when publishing.

In short, I use a container class (Node) to include all listeners on a specific type, when a message is published, all listeners on the exact same message type will be invoked.

Importantly, besides this barebone functionality, I would like notify the subscribers on the superclass of the message as well (as an example, a subscriber on Fruit class should be notified when an Apple is published). For such a purpose, the Node class need to contain other Nodes which cater to its super type. The graph is maintained when subscribing/unsubscribing. When a message is published, all super type Nodes will be called recursively.

The attempt below is a port from my Java implementation. The problem I have encountered with the design is around the generic type casting.

```cs
public delegate void Consumer<in X>(X obj);

public class PubSubImpl : PubSub
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Node> nodes;

    public PubSubImpl()
    {
        nodes = new Dictionary<Type, Node>();
    }

    public int Invoke<T>(T obj)
    {
        Node node = nodes.GetOrDefault(obj.GetType(), CreateNode<T>);
        return node.Invoke(obj);
    }


    private Node CreateNode<T>(Type type)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        foreach(var entry in nodes)
        {
            //if new type is a sub type of this node
            if(entry.Key.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                node.superTypes.Add(entry.Value);
            }
            if(type.IsAssignableFrom(entry.Key))
            {
                entry.Value.superTypes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        nodes.Add(type, node);
        return node;
    }

    public void Subscribe<T>(object subscriber, Consumer<T> action)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        Node node = nodes.GetOrDefault(type, CreateNode<T>);
        node.handlers.Add(new Handler(subscriber, action));
        Debug.Log("Handlers now: " + type + " " + node.handlers.Count);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe<T>(object subscriber, Consumer<T> action)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        Node node = nodes.GetOrDefault(type, CreateNode<T>);
        node.handlers.RemoveWhere(h => h.subscriber == subscriber && h.action == action);
    }

    public void UnsubscribeAll(object subscriber)
    {
        foreach(Node n in nodes.Values)
        {
            n.handlers.RemoveWhere(h => h.subscriber == subscriber);
        }
    }

    internal class Node
    {
        public readonly HashSet<Node> superTypes;
        public readonly HashSet<Handler> handlers;

        public Node()
        {
            superTypes = new HashSet<Node>();
            handlers = new HashSet<Handler>();
        }

        public int Invoke<T>(T payload)
        {
            int res = 0;
            foreach(Handler handler in handlers)
            {
                Debug.Log(handler.action.GetType());
/****************************************************************
NOTE: This is where I am shooting myself in the foot. 
In Java, type erasure allows me to do some crazy stuff as long as I promise to maintain the internal structure. 
In C# where we have strong type, it seems I can't have both covariance and contravariance here.
****************************************************************/

                ((Consumer<???>)handler.action)(payload);
                res++;
            }
            foreach(Node node in superTypes)
            {
                res += node.Invoke(payload);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    internal class Handler
    {
        public readonly object subscriber;
        public readonly Delegate action;

        public Handler(object subscriber, Delegate action)
        {
            this.subscriber = subscriber;
            this.action = action;
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if anyone can show me how this can be achieved in C#, any workaround or even suggestion of alternative data structure is much appreciated.

**Edit**

Found out that the root cause is because of the NET version (Unity3D by default uses .NET 3.5...duh). After upgrading .NET version, the casting works like a charm! As an example the casting which works in 4.x but not 3.5 is below

```cs
Consumer<Fruit> fruitConsumer = (f) => {};
Consumer<Apple> apple = (Consumer<Apple>)fruitConsumer;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but I don't see where you remove from the superTypes list message types that have been unsubscribed. Shouldn't this message type be completely removed?

Comment: @selalerer not sure what you mean here. Suppose we have Apple->TreeFruit->Fruit hierarchy, and I am subscribing to Apple, then If I unsubscribe, I will only need to touch the Apple Node. Subscribers on TreeFruit and Fruit nodes need not be touched at all.

Comment: If you register a subscriber to Fruit it also gets registered in the superTypes of Apple. When you unregister this subscriber it only gets deleted from Fruit but not from Apple's superTypes

Comment: @selalerer I understand your point. I think this is a less important topic and subject to opinions. You may think leaving a dangling Node will spin CPU unnecessarily, where I may think that because I have very frequent sub/unsub on Fruit I may wish to keep that Node there instead of keep deleting/re-instantiating it. Could you help with the problem I try to solve here instead? If it helps, maybe you can ignore all my code besides the contract (sub, unsub, invoke), and try to implement it.

Comment: You can maybe make your `Consumer` an `interface` instead of a `delegate` and have for it a method `Consume(object obj)` and then your subscribers just take an object. It seems to me that in Java you didn't really have type safety too.